# Can we add tags for popular 3d programs?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it intended that there are basically no tags here for application-specific questions?

Stuff like Blender, Maya, Sketchup, Houdini, 3DS max, etc.

Answer (score 3):

(I could be wrong but ...) I think it's okay that we don't have these tags because it's off topic to ask questions about using any of these pieces of software. For Blender, we'd send you to Blender.SE. And for the others, maybe SuperUser?

It's possible that some of these tags could show up here, but I think the likelihood is low. It would require the question to be about the software without being *about the software*. Like maybe if someone was writing code to create a data file for use with one of these programs. A question about graphics programming in that context is possible. But if it were about any other aspect of the software, then there are other sites that are better suited.

Another useful perspective on tags is the question: "Is it a 'meta-' tag?" That is, **Could this tag ever stand alone on a question on this site?** I think the answer is no for these (to this question at least).

A similar question has been discussed on the Music Practice & Theory site about whether to have tags for composers (`Bach`, `Beethoven`, `Mozart`, etc.). It seems bizarre at first, but it turns out these aren't very useful tags for questions about practice and theory. I think a similar logic applies here.

Comment: Dont send to graphic design. While graphic design is ambivalent on 3d you really need to ask a graphic design question. Just because you do graphics does not mean you qualify for graphic design.